# Unable to bind columns for the DataGrid that resides inside RowDetail of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

So, I have to build a `UserControl` that holds the `DataGrid`.  Each `Row` of the `DataGrid` will have another `DataGrid` that holds the Details of the Row respectively.

Initially, I faced some problem to bind the `Columns` for both the `DataGrids` from caller to `UserControl` as the `Columns` are not DP, then I overcome it with an attached property.

So this is how the sample looks.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <local:CustomDataGrid >
        <local:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emp Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </local:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
        <local:CustomDataGrid.RowDetailColumns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manager Name" Binding="{Binding ManagerName}" />
        </local:CustomDataGrid.RowDetailColumns>
    </local:CustomDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var emps = new List<Employee>();
        emps.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "aaa", Details = new List<Manager>() { new Manager() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "Maaa" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 22, ManagerName = "Mbbb" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 33, ManagerName = "Mccc" } } });
        emps.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "aaa", Details = new List<Manager>() { new Manager() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "Maaa" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 22, ManagerName = "Mbbb" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 33, ManagerName = "Mccc" } } });
        emps.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "aaa", Details = new List<Manager>() { new Manager() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "Maaa" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 22, ManagerName = "Mbbb" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 33, ManagerName = "Mccc" } } });
        emps.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "aaa", Details = new List<Manager>() { new Manager() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "Maaa" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 22, ManagerName = "Mbbb" }, new Manager() { ManagerID = 33, ManagerName = "Mccc" } } });
        Employees = emps;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Manager> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomDataGrid.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details}" local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding RowDetailColumns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>  
</Grid>
```

**CustomDataGrid.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustomDataGrid.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CustomDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Columns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        RowDetailColumns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register("Columns"
                   , typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)
                   , typeof(CustomDataGrid));


    public static DependencyProperty RowDetailColumnsProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("RowDetailColumns"
                  , typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)
                  , typeof(CustomDataGrid));

    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> RowDetailColumns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(RowDetailColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowDetailColumnsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**DataGridColumnsBehavior.cs  ///Attached Property for columns**

```
public static class DataGridColumnsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                            typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                            typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
    private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
        ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        if (columns == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
            if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                if (ne.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
            }
        };
    }
    public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

**Problem:**  With the code, I am able to bind the columns of the parent DataGrid and it works as expected, but ***in the childDatagrid (in RowDetail) I can see only the detail of the first row and exception thrown on rest***.

**Exception details:**

[image]

Any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/ImageOfAnException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing line 32 (in `BindableColumnsPropertyChanged`) of the attached behavior with this code

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
{
    DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn() ;
    col.Binding = ((DataGridTextColumn)column).Binding;
    col.Header = column.Header;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Comment: Headers got hided with this solution.   Do you know why?

Comment: Likely because they've to be copied too. Will double check and edit my answer soon.

Comment: Correct, changing `dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);` to `col.Header = column.Header;dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);` should do the trick.

Comment: Also, it is more specific to `DataGridTextColumn ` le t me try it in generic way of cloning.  Pls share if you know.  thanks.

Comment: Of course you can copy also `Width` an so on... But *afaik* it's the [only way](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe627934-9e3d-49ca-bee6-5faabe7deb44/wpf-cloning-datagrid-does-not-preserve-visual-markup?forum=wpf#59fe64c3-601d-41c9-bb68-a66ea2386c12) to clone it (you don't need this work-around when `DisplayIndex < 0`). Should I find something better, I'll share.